# Installing Sublime Text 3 on Mac with ST 2 installed

Tags: sublimetext3, osx-elcapitan

Is it OK to install ST3 on Mac OSX 10.11.2 which has ST2 installed? and what things I need to look out for?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean your only going to get benefits as you go up the chain so here are some(from hundreds):

- Speed. Startup time, file load time, and Replace All have all been
  significantly improved. If you're using OS X with a Retina display,
  then you'll find huge rendering speed improvements too.
- Symbol Indexing, for Goto Definition and Goto Symbol in Project.
  Complementing these are the Jump Forward and Jump Back features.
  Improved HTML Editing, including tag and attribute completion as well
  as automatic tag closing.
- Improved Project and Pane management, including multiple workspaces
  for a single project.
- Richer API. Plugins are better insulated from the application, and
  now have a broader and fully threadsafe API to work with.

I have sublime text 3, and its the best code-editor ive used. Dont worry get sublime text 3 as it will only get better :)